# Laravel Voyager image broken after uploading in server

Tags: php, cpanel, laravel-5.6, voyager

Laravel Version: 5.5
Voyager Version: 1.0
PHP Version: 7

I have uploaded my laravel project in cPanel. Previous images are shown successfully but the newly added images are not showing.

[image]

Here last 2 images are already in the project before uploading in cPanel. After uploading the project successfully in cPanel I have try to upload an image but it is not shown which is first one.

Anybody help ?

i tryed with change in config/filesystem.php

Change the path from storage_path() to public_path().

```
'public' => [ 'driver' => 'local', 'root' => public_path('app/public'), 'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage', 'visibility' => 'public', ],
```

but it not worked. please help me!

broken image url- http://example.com/storage/products/December2018/QIDyzoFg1aAf6NUGMJtZ.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution ! the promblem was in the symlink(storage symbolic link).
 in the localhost we can easily create the symlink from voyager adminpannel or in terminal
`php artisan storage:link` 
in that case in shared hosting we cannot do that .see below what i do.

1.log in to the cpannel

2.go the project folder then go public->storage folder then rename it to storage old or somthing.

3.come back to the cpannel main menu and select the cron job

4.in common settings --> select *once per 5 minutes

5.in the command field add this
       `ln -s /home/cpanel_username/project_name/storage/app/public /home/cpanel_sername/project_name/public/storage`

**(my site was in subdomain**) example-`ln -s /home/your_cpannel_user name/public_html/subdomain_foldername/storage/app/public /home/cpanel_username/public_html/subdomain_foldername/public/storage`

syntax-->`ln -s target_path link_path`

6.type your email in the cron email and update email(when the job was done email notification wiil come to your inbox **check the spam folder**)

6.create new cronjob

7.wait few minutes you almost done.! **after the execution delete the cronjob**

8.log and check upload path working correctly!

Comment: It works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Laravel project "public" directory and "public_html" directory are different, please run the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This command will create symlink to "public" directory to your Laravel project, not inside the "public_html". Next we'll need to move the "storage" link to "public_html" directory, for this you can move directly. If it doesn't work then go inside the "public" directory and run the below command according to your public_html directory location:

```
mv storage /home/*yourHostinInfo*/domains/*domainName*/public_html
```

The path might be different based on your hosting information.